# How can I avoid my opponents' defense breaks?

Tags: assassins-creed

I'm Italian and I'm playing the Italian version of the game, so sorry, I don't know the name of the combat maneuver. I will try to explain:

From the 5th block (I think), you can break the enemy's defense and your foes can do the same. When I was in a large fight, I used to wait for the opponents to attack in order to counterattack. However, now that this move it available, every time they break my defense with that move. How can I avoid my opponents' defense breaks?

Answer (score 7):

Dodge. A quick hop away from the enemy (or a sidestep) is almost always enough to get you out of reach, before the blow has time to strike.

To dodge, suddenly begin moving away from the enemy and press the dodge button at the same time. The dodge button is <kbd>A</kbd> on the Xbox 360, <kbd>X</kbd> on the PS3 and <kbd>Space</kbd> on the PC.